# How to get Numbers from user store them until they type -1 and than add all the numbers up toghterr

Tags: c#, loops, input, output, addition

Hey i am trying to figure out the best way to get numbers from a user and than once the user types -1 it will add up all the numbers

Comment: If you hope to get help from folks here you will want to share what you have tried so far. Everyone is great about helping but no one is here to do people's homework or job for them. Show us what you have and we'll see what we can do to help improve/fix it.

Comment: See [How do I ask Homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does as your question's described, you can test it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aicWda)

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your numbers below, 1 per line");
        string input = "";
        int inputNumber = 0;
        while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "-1"){
            if(int.TryParse(input, out inputNumber)){
               numbers.Add(inputNumber);
            }
        }
        int sum = numbers.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine("Total Sum: " + sum);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please don't do someone else's homework.

Comment: Also mind that `inputNumber` is invalid if `TryParse` returns `false`.

Comment: @Fildor added code as per suggestion